# Make anchortext part of href?

Tags: javascript, html, http, anchor, href

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/?q=">Hello world</a>
```

Is it possible to render this into [Hello World](https://www.google.com/?q=Hello%20world)?

The link should point to [https://www.google.com/?q=Hello world](https://www.google.com/?q=Hello%20world) without specifying this in the href.

I am thinking javascript is probably the best way of doing this?

Any help would be good!

Comment: It can be done with script, but surely the server is the "best way of doing this"?

Comment: Since many of the answers here use click event handlers, I'd like to note that click events on links aren't very accessible - for example, attempting to open this in a new tab will break. It's probably better to loop through all links on a page on load, if it must be done on the client side.

Comment: RobG is correct, why concatenate a new href on the fly? Do you have a really compelling reason not append to the href when you're setting the inner text?

Comment: @liu-kang, did any of the answers below solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
<a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/?q=" onclick='window.location.href = this.href+encodeURI(this.textContent); return false; '>Hello world</a>
```

Added `onclick` event handler and get the `href` and `textContent` of the tag and combine them together. Then it will give the expected result.

**Updated:**  If you have lot of links in your page, then you can create javascript function and call it wherever necessary.

**Javascript:**

```
 function Search(d){
     window.location.href = d.href+encodeURI(d.textContent); 
    return false; 
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/?q=" onclick='Search(this);'>Hello world</a>
```

Even if you feel to integrate jquery, the process may get simpler.

Comment: This actually works. I will probobly have many links like this on a single page, will this type of inline JS slow down the website?

Comment: @Liu Kang I have updated answer with function for reuse.

Answer (score 6):

assuming your `href` is always in format `https://www.google.com/?q=`, you could do:

```
var eles = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = eles.length; i < len; i++) {
    //get the inner html of anchor tag
    //var text = eles[i].innerHTML;
    //better use textContent
    var text = eles[i].textContent;
    //append anchor tag inner html to href
    eles[i].href += text;
}
```

Comment: Probably better to use *textContent* or *innerText* than *innerHTML*.

Comment: And if you want/need to support IE8 (urgh), `eles[i].textContent || eles[i].innerText || ''`

Answer (score 1):

```
text = $(".link").html();
link = $(".link").attr('href');
$(".link").attr('href',link+text);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can help you

Javascript

```
function changeHref () {
        var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        anchor.href += anchor.textContent;
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="link" onclick="changeHref()" href="https://www.google.com/?q=">Hello world</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/rudobe/edit?html,js,output

HTML:

```
<a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/?q=">Hello world</a>
```

JS:

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0];
var href = anchor.getAttribute('href');
var text = anchor.textContent;
anchor.setAttribute('href', href + text); // The `+` operator concatenates here.
```

DOCS:

http://devdocs.io/dom/element.setattribute

http://devdocs.io/dom/element.getattribute

http://devdocs.io/dom/node.textcontent

http://devdocs.io/dom/document.getelementsbyclassname

Comment: What about [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-links)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', this.href + encodeURIComponent($(this).text()));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xrbn2/)

This would change the href attribute before the link is submitted

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the onclick event of javascript:

```
<a class="link" href="#" onclick="navigateToLink(this)">Hello world</a>
```

In javascript then you can handle it like this:

```
function navigateToLink(elt){
   console.log("https://www.google.com/?q="+elt.textContent );
   window.location.href="https://www.google.com/?q="+ elt.textContent;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dKc2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers, so one more won't hurt. Presumably you don't have control of the server, otherwise you'd just modify the href there and be done with it. A simple method is:

```
<a href="..." onclick="this.href+=this.textContent||this.innerText">...</a>
```

Using *textContent* or *innerText* means you can have markup in the content of the link and it won't be part of the href.

A more general solution to modify just the links with "google.com" in the href is:

```
function modifyLinks() {
  var link, links = document.links;
  var re = /google\.com/i;

  for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    link = links[i];

    if (re.test(link.href)) {
      link.href += link.textContent || link.innerText;
    }
  }
}

window.onload = modifyLinks;
```

The test can be changed to anything, maybe you want to base it on *className* or some other property. If you want to modify all links, just remove the test.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').on('click', function(){
        var temp = $(this).attr('href');
        var html = $(this).html();
        $(this).attr('href',temp+html);
    });
});
```